# Had done vs. done beforehand

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

when it comes to SHOWING which went first between TWO past events, what is the difference of using HAD done to done beforehand. For example:

> I **had** read books **before** I took the examination.

Vs.

> - I read books **beforehand** **before** I took the examination OR
> - I read books **first** **before** I took the examination.

Does "had done" just more proper than just the typical "beforehand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: "read" in all these examples is the past-tense version (rhymes with "red")

## 1. Completed vs. Possibly Ongoing actions

First, "beforehand" and "before" are distractions. Your two examples are different because they are making a choice between the two main past tenses in English: the [past perfect](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) tense and [simple past](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html) (or "imperfect past") tense.

#### Actions in the past that ended in the past:  Past Perfect tense ("have ___", "be ___")

- I **had read** books before I took the examination

This means that, in the past, you read the books, and finished that task. Because "read books" is a very general statement, your use of the perfect tense suggests that reading books was something you did before that examination, but it is not something that you did afterwards.

#### Actions in the past that may not be finished now:  Simple Past tense

- I **read** books before I took the examination

In this case, you're still saying that you read the books before the examination, but you're not saying anything about whether you did afterwards.

## 2. "before" joins clauses, "beforehand" modifies a clause

With the grammar out of the way, look at your three sentences again. You have three things that you're saying in all of these sentences:

- "*I read books*",
- "*I took the examination"*
- the reading of the books happened at an earlier time than the examination:

Here are your sentences again, and I've put the two actions in brackets to make my explanation a little bit clearer:

1. (I had read books) before (I took the examination).

This is fine. It tells me you read the books, and when you did the exam.

2. (I read books beforehand) before (I took the examination)
3. (I read books first) before (I took the examination)

These two aren't strictly wrong, but they're not well-written - you have redundant words in both. To see why, we have to look at what the word "before" is doing in these sentences. It is joining the two clauses (it's a conjunction), but also it's saying that these things happened in a particular order. *X* is "I read books", *Y* is "I took the examination", and "*X* before *Y*" means "*X* was earlier in time than *Y*".   Your simplest sentence is therefore:

- (I read books) **before** (I took the examination).

(yes, this is like your first sentence, but the tense of the verb, "to read", is different)

Meanwhile, "first" and "beforehand" are modifiers: they change the meaning of the verb "read", to say that its action came before some other action. However, the conjunction "before" also tells me the order of these two actions, so there was no need to use "first" or "beforehand" when talking about the first action.